# Using Dropzone.js to upload after new user creation, send headers

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dropzone.js

I'm using a great plugin - dropzone.js (dropzonejs.com) to make my site a little more fancy when registering a new user.

Basically, the user fills out a form, drops a couple images into the "dropzone", and clicks "Submit", which fires an ajax call that posts the form to a php script.

I have dropzone parameters set to enqueForUpload:false, which keeps the files from auto-uploading, since I need them to upload into uploads/$userid, after the new user id has been created. I can give dropzone header params, which I'm assuming post to the url, similar to an ajax call, instead of data: {'userid': userid}, dropzone uses headers: {'userid': userid}... However, dropzone gets initialized on document.ready, and as the userid variable isn't declared yet, dropzone fails to initialize.

I'm guessing I'm going to need to initialize dropzone with document.ready, but not give it headers just yet. Then after the ajax form processing is successful and returns userid, call dropzone to upload and give it the headers at that point. Problem is, I don't know what code would need to be called to make that happen.

Initialize Dropzone on ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#dropzone').dropzone({
    url: 'dropzoneprocess.php',
    maxFilesize: 1,
    paramName: 'photos',
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    enqueueForUpload: false,
  });
});
```

Then...

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(){
    validation crap here
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'postform.php',
        data: {'various': form, 'values': here}
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function(data){
           var userid = data.userid;

    /* (and this is what I can't figure out:)
    tell dropzone to upload, and make it 
    post userid to 'dropzone.php' */

     });
});
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you use the latest Dropzone version, the parameter `enqueueForUpload` has been removed, in favour of `autoProcessQueue` which makes the whole queuing easier.

So, just call `myDropzone.processQueue()` as soon as you want all files to be uploaded.

To add additional parameters to the `XHR` you can simply register to the `sending` event, which gets the `xhr` object as second and `formData` as third parameter, and add the data yourself. Something like this:

```
myDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
  // add headers with xhr.setRequestHeader() or
  // form data with formData.append(name, value);
});
```

Comment: I'm curious as to the use of `.append`. I've never seen that method used on an object and why doesn't `formData.name="value"` work?

Comment: hello, no idea why it is not working, but you can find the same finding in article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21942314/sending-additional-data-with-programatically-created-dropzone-using-the-sending in the answer

Comment: @NicolasMoise see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

Answer (score 4):

I used enyo answer, but i used many dropzones with data-id attribute in my page so I used:

```
$('div.dropzone').dropzone({
    url: 'img.php'
});
var sendingHandler = function(file, xhr, formData) {
    formData.append('id', $(this.element).data('id'));
};
$('div.dropzone').each(function() {
    Dropzone.forElement(this).on('sending', sendingHandler);
});
```

Comment: Instead of iterating twice over the `.dropzone` elements, you can simple use the `init: function() { }` config, and setup the `sending` event listener there.