# Sending additional data with programatically created Dropzone using the sending event

Tags: node.js, angularjs, dropzone.js

I have the following (simplified for example) angular directive which creates a dropzone

```
directives.directive('dropzone', ['dropZoneFactory', function(dropZoneFactory){
    'use strict';
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link : function(scope, element, attrs){

            new Dropzone('#'+attrs.id, {url: attrs.url});

            var myDropZone = Dropzone.forElement('#'+attrs.id);


            myDropZone.on('sending', function(file, xhr, formData){
                //this gets triggered
                console.log('sending');
                formData.userName='bob';
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

As you can see the the `sending` event handler I'm trying to send the username ("bob") along with the uploaded file. However, I can't seem to retrieve it in my route middleware as `req.params` comes back as an empty array (I've also tried `req.body`).

**My node route**

```
    {
    path: '/uploads',
    httpMethod: 'POST',
    middleware: [express.bodyParser({ keepExtensions: true, uploadDir: 'uploads'}),function(request,response){
        // comes back as []
        console.log(request.params);

        //this sees the files fine
        console.log(request.files);

        response.end("upload complete");
    }]
}
```

Here is what the docs say on the `sending` event

> Called just before each file is sent. Gets the xhr object and the formData objects as second and third parameters, so you can modify them (for example to add a CSRF token) or add additional data.

**EDIT**

I dropped the programmatic approach for now. I have two forms submitting to the same endpoint, a regular one with just post and a dropzone one. Both work, so I don't think it's an issue with the endpoint rather with how I handle the 'sending' event.

```
//Receives the POST var just fine
form(action="http://127.0.0.1:3000/uploads", method="post", id="mydz")
    input(type="hidden", name="additionaldata", value="1")
    input(type="submit")

//With this one I can get the POST var
form(action="http://127.0.0.1:3000/uploads", method="post", id="mydz2", class="dropzone")
    input(type="hidden", name="additionaldata", value="1")
```

Comment: Hi Nicolas. I suspect it's related to the way you're configuring Express. I've never seen such configuration. Would you mind giving much details on how you create and configure your routes ? Generally, we configure routes [this way](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB)

Comment: I doubt it. I've sent a regular html form to the same endpoint and it all works smoothly so I think the problem is how I send the data through Dropzone. Do you have an example where sending the data works? I've also tried the way they have in their [FAQ](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/FAQ)  (dropzone in the html as oppsoed to creating progamatically) but it also doesn't work.

Comment: How did you send your userName in your html form ? as query or form parameter ?

Comment: @Feugy see edit, it;'s a form parameters send through post

Comment: Actually It's working now with the second form. However, if I try to do it programmatically (`myDropZone.on('sending', ...`), it doesn't work. Any clue?

Comment: I could modify my directive to create a form like in my second example, but it sucks that you can't do it programmatically.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

OK, I've actually figured it out, thanks to [Using Dropzone.js to upload after new user creation, send headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378500/using-dropzone-js-to-upload-after-new-user-creation-send-headers)

The `sending` event:

```
        myDropZone.on('sending', function(file, xhr, formData){
            formData.append('userName', 'bob');
        });
```

As opposed to `formData.userName = 'bob'` which doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to NicolasMoise's answer. 
As a beginner in webdev I got stuck on how to obtain an instance of Dropzone. I wanted to retrieve an instance of Dropzone that had been generated by the autodiscovery feature. But it turns out that the easiest way to do this is to manually add a Dropzone instance after first telling Dropzone **not** to auto-discover.

```
<input id="pathInput"/>
<div id="uploadForm" class="dropzone"/> 
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var dZone = new Dropzone("div#uploadForm", {url: "/api/uploads"});
    dZone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, data){
      data.append("uploadFolder", $("#pathInput")[0].value);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Serverside the data will be in `request.body.uploadFolder`

Answer (score 1):

Nicolas answer is one possible solution to the problem. It is especially useful if you need to alter the `file` object prior to sending.

An alternative is to use the `params` option:

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myId", 
                              { url: "/file/post", params: { 'param_1': 1 }});
```

cf. [the documention](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#tips)

Answer (score 0):

For those that are using [thatisuday/ng-dropzone](https://github.com/thatisuday/ng-dropzone) the callback methods are done as such:

```
    <ng-dropzone class="dropzone" options="dzOptions" callbacks="dzCallbacks" methods="dzMethods"></ng-dropzone>
```

In a controller:

```
    $scope.dzCallbacks = {
        sending: function(file, xhr, form) {
            console.log('custom sending', arguments);
            form.append('a', 'b');
        }
    };
```